# javascript "for (x in y)" statements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

```
//just copied this code from w3schools
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25}; 

for (x in person)
{
document.write(person[x] + " ");
}
```

I want to know that, what I have to assume instead of "x".

Comment: Can you specify a little more? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Make sure you declare `x` first...

Comment: for a better reference look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in and why so, look here: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Avoid using for in. Use `for(var i=0;i<person.length;i++)` instead.

Comment: Could you explain why? @OptimusCrime

Comment: @Alexander for is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `person` is object and `X` is variable used in iteration of the `for` loop, you can name it anything other than `X` also :). Here `X` works as `key` of the object for example:

```
alert(person["fname"]);
```

Here `fname` is stored in `X` along with other keys such as `lname` and `age`.

Comment: The example with the alert should be `person["fname"]` rather than `person[fname]`.

Answer (score 6):

You want to have

```
for ( x in Object.keys(person)) {
  console.log(person[x]);
}
```

this will give you a list of KEYS rather than a list of values.